# how to assign IP address into a newly created VMware from esxi commandline

Tags: esxi

I have done the following steps:

1. created a new VM:
    --> vim-cmd solo/registervm test_vm.vmx
2. powering on the VM
    --> im-cmd vmsvc/power.on

Now I want to assign the IP address into this VM from the ESXI console. how can I do it. I do not want to use GUI.

Answer (score 0):

1 . change the server management ip address
2. Update the DNS server entries
3. Restart the server management network
4. Restart the management agents
5. Reconnect host to vcenter
6.login to vcenter server web client
7. Select connection